# Don't indent first level of tree in a recursive tree printer

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I would like to refactor a recursive tree-printing function I wrote so that the root node, the first call, is not indented at all.

```py
Tree = dict[str, 'Tree']
def print_tree(tree: Tree, prefix: str=''):
    if not tree:
        return
    markers = [('├── ', '│   '), ('└── ', '    ')]
    children = list(tree.items())
    for key, subtree in children:
        is_last_child = (key, subtree) == children[-1]
        key_prefix, subtree_prefix = markers[is_last_child]
        print(prefix + key_prefix + key)
        print_tree(subtree, prefix + subtree_prefix)

tree = {'.': {'alpha':{}, 'beta': {'beta.alpha':{}, 'beta.beta':{}}, 'charlie': {'charlie.alpha':{}, 'charlie.beta':{}, 'charlie.charlie':{}}, 'delta':{}}}
print_tree(tree)
```

Current output is

```
└── .
    ├── alpha
    ├── beta
    │   ├── beta.alpha
    │   └── beta.beta
    ├── charlie
    │   ├── charlie.alpha
    │   ├── charlie.beta
    │   └── charlie.charlie
    └── delta
```

But I would like the output to be

```
.
├── alpha
├── beta
│   ├── beta.alpha
│   └── beta.beta
├── charlie
│   ├── charlie.alpha
│   ├── charlie.beta
│   └── charlie.charlie
└── delta
```

I can't think of a way to do it elegantly, as in without special-casing the first call like this:

```py
def print_tree(tree: Tree, prefix: str='', root: bool=True):
    if not tree:
        return
    markers = [('├── ', '│   '), ('└── ', '    ')]
    if root:
        markers = [('', ''), ('', '')]
    children = list(tree.items())
    for key, subtree in children:
        is_last_child = (key, subtree) == children[-1]
        key_prefix, subtree_prefix = markers[is_last_child]
        print(prefix + key_prefix + key)
        print_tree(subtree, prefix + subtree_prefix, root=False)
```

How can I change the way I'm recursing to accomplish this? I don't want to add an extra argument to the function or otherwise require more information about state. I like how simple my current function is, it just prefixes the first level when I don't really want it to.

Comment: If you had more than one root key, the output would be kind of ambiguous. Is that what you want? Or will there only ever be one root key? For example, it'd be impossible to tell apart the output of `print_tree({'a': {}, 'b': {}})` and `print_tree({'a': {}}); print_tree({'b': {}})`.

Answer (score 1):

Beautiful algorithm, I like it! <sup>(Much better than [mine](https://github.com/ManderaGeneral/generallibrary/blob/3d3fc94dc1774c93f80db2d8f95eae95cf102413/generallibrary/diagram.py#L508))</sup>

This is the best I could do with your given restraints:

```py
Tree = dict[str, 'Tree']
def print_tree(tree: Tree, prefix: str=None):
    markers = [('├── ', '│   '), ('└── ', '    '), ('', '')]
    for i, (key, subtree) in enumerate(tree.items()):
        is_last_child = i == len(tree) - 1
        marker_index = 2 if prefix is None else is_last_child
        prefix = prefix or ""
        key_prefix, subtree_prefix = markers[marker_index]
        print(prefix + key_prefix + key)
        print_tree(subtree, prefix + subtree_prefix)

tree = {'.': {'alpha':{}, 'beta': {'beta.alpha':{}, 'beta.beta':{}}, 'charlie': {'charlie.alpha':{}, 'charlie.beta':{}, 'charlie.charlie':{}}, 'delta':{}}}
print_tree(tree)
```

```
.
├── alpha
├── beta
│   ├── beta.alpha
│   └── beta.beta
├── charlie
│   ├── charlie.alpha
│   ├── charlie.beta
│   └── charlie.charlie
└── delta
```

- Storing the `root` indicator inside the `prefix` by making the default `None`
- Added a third marker option which only root uses
- Replaced `children` list with `enumerate` using `i` to check if it's the last child
- Removed unnecessary empty tree check

Answer (score 0):

It does not yet do what you want, but you can maybe tweak it.

Basically, I've just added a level parameter to track where you are at.  It defaults to 0 so your initial call is much the same.

```
Tree = dict[str, 'Tree']
def print_tree(tree: Tree, prefix: str='',level=0):
    # level starts out at zero....
    if not tree:
        return
    markers = [('├── ', '│   '), ('└── ', '    ')]
    children = list(tree.items())
    for key, subtree in children:
        is_last_child = (key, subtree) == children[-1]
        key_prefix, subtree_prefix = markers[is_last_child]

        #only if on level 1+
        if level:
            #hack to avoid the extra blanks on the left
            print((prefix + key_prefix + key).lstrip())
        print_tree(subtree, prefix + subtree_prefix,level=level+1)


tree = {'.': {'alpha':{}, 'beta': {'beta.alpha':{}, 'beta.beta':{}}, 'charlie': {'charlie.alpha':{}, 'charlie.beta':{}, 'charlie.charlie':{}}, 'delta':{}}}


print_tree(tree)
```

#### output:

```
├── alpha
├── beta
│   ├── beta.alpha
│   └── beta.beta
├── charlie
│   ├── charlie.alpha
│   ├── charlie.beta
│   └── charlie.charlie
└── delta
```

Awesome little thing, looks much like the Linux `tree` utility, which I have long wanted to filter somehow.  Probably will re-use your code, once I've understood how it works.

Hmmm, on second reading, that does look a bit like your special-casing first call.  Oh well...